# Can't install guzzlehttp

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I am using PHP 5.6 and I have Laravel 5.4 for my development. When I try to install guzzlehttp through composer for my Laravel I get error that my requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.. 
[cmd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJk7Z.png)

here's my composer.json

[composer.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlyNl.png)

what should i do. Thank you

Comment: Composer has given you an error message. Under “Problem 1” is says `laravelcollective/html` is locked to a conflicting version, so what does your **composer.json** file look like?

Comment: "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
    },

Comment: use below command composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"

Comment: @BalkrushnaMaheta that worked perfectly thank you :)